I wanted to fetch the valid email addresses from a table in bigquery with rules given below
Let's consider 2 cases with examples

If the email looks like below,
abc@gmail.com
Then, I wanted the query to fetch this email id as there are exactly 3 characters followed by a dot. If it looks like, abc@gmail.co, then the query should not pick this record.

If the email id looks like below,
abc.xyz@gmail.com
Then, I wanted the query to fetch the email id as there are exactly 3 characters followed by the last dot where there are multiple dots in a email id and if there's only 1 or 2 characters after the last dot, it should not pick that record .


For the first case, I tried using below query,
Select regexp_contains (email, r'[A-Za-z0-9]{3}.')
This returns true even if there are only 2 characters after a dot.
I tried lot of ways and not able to figure out the logic. Can anyone please help in framing the logic and explain it.

In (1) you showed "abc@gmail.com" and said "there are exactly 3 characters followed by a dot" ... I'm confused ... no-where in the above is there 3 characters followed by a dot.

Another option to consider
select email, length(net.public_suffix(email)) = 3 as to_pick_or_not 
from your_table 


You question/lanaguage is not very easy to understand but see if this helps:
select email, regexp_contains(email, r'\.[A-Za-z]{3}$') as to_pick_or_not 
from 
(select 'abc@gmail.com' as email 
union all 
select 'abc@gmail.co' as email 
union all 
select 'abc.xyz@gmail.com' as email 
)

gives:

